# What can I do with the truck near the SS Anne?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

There is a swim glitch at the SS Anne if you save your game in front of the sailor and use swim after restarting the game and swim through him.

When you swim in the water where the SS Anne is there is a truck on the right side on the land.

What can I do with this truck? I heard some rumors about getting Mew here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The truck does nothing.

In the remakes (Fire Red and Leaf Green) you can find a Lava cookie below the truck, but in the original games, the truck is useless.

It could be leftover from a purpose that it was going to have but was removed, or it could have just been placed there to confuse players.

[Source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/S.S._Anne#Rumors)

Comment: And what about the rumors about mew?

Comment: @MaartenKuilman They're all false. There are other ways to obtain Mew (http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mew_glitch) just not from the truck.